# inline text contained within a grid item will not truncate with an ellipsis

Tags: html, css, overflow

I can't seem to get the ellipsis to display. The text just wraps to the next line.

```css
text {
   display: inline;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-align: center;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

grid {
   width: 200px;
   height: 3em;
   border: 1px solid #000000ff;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}
```

```html
<grid><text>This text should display an ellipsis instead of wrapping!</text></grid>
```

Comment: you forget `white-space:nowrap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `white-space: nowrap;`to `text`

```css
text {
   display: inline;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-align: center;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   white-space: nowrap;
}

grid {
   width: 200px;
   height: 3em;
   border: 1px solid #000000ff;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}
```

```html
<grid><text>This text should display an ellipsis instead of wrapping!</text></grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please apply css for nowrap to the text, as following:

```css
text {
       display: inline;
       overflow: hidden;
       text-align: center;
       white-space: nowrap;
       text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
    
    grid {
       width: 200px;
       height: 3em;
       border: 1px solid #000000ff;
       display: grid;
       grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
```

```html
<grid><text>This text should display an ellipsis instead of wrapping!</text></grid>
```